# To use layout_marginLeft in a button style applied as a theme?

Tags: android, button, coding-style, themes, margins

I used an attribute `layout_marginLeft="30dip"` in a style defined for buttons. When I apply this style individually for each button, the left margin is placed as I wanted.

But then I defined a theme, where I assigned my button style to the attribute `android:buttonStyle` and applied it to my project.
However, the left margin property is ignored. Any idea what I must do here?

style.xml as follows:

```
<style name="btnstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">30dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>       
</style> 

<style name="appstyle" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/btnstyle</item> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 14):

It looks like this can be achieved by wrapping an insets tag around the shape.

Like this:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="5dp"
    android:insetRight="5dp"
    android:insetTop="5dp"
    android:insetBottom="5dp">

<shape  
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid 
        android:color="#fff"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#333"/>
    <corners 
        android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
</inset>
```

Comment: after many attempts this was the only that works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

There is an awesome answer [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13365288/969325). Basically `LayoutParams` (layout_) are used for child views to tell their parent `ViewGroup` how they should be positioned. But `LayoutParams` are specific to each `ViewGroup` type (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` etc.) so `LayoutParams` can not be generalized in this way for a theme.

All this is very unfortunate as you can't use completely generalized styles in a theme but you can still use the style for each specific view where you need it, like following:

```
<Button style="@style/btnstyle"/>
```

Comment: How does the Buttons have margins by default then? How does the framework do it?

Comment: @Nilzor buttons don't have margins, they have grafic that has build in margin/padding. Check the resource folder and you'll see. if you set the background graphic to something else the buttons will not have any margin

Comment: Thanks. So I guess that is an approach anyone designing their own buttons can take as well.

Comment: @Nilzor Yes but in reality it's more like padding than margin :)

Answer (score 3):

Ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue; all margin attributes are ignored when applied to a Button or ImageButton via a style within a theme.

However, I've found it *does* work when the style is applied directly using the "style" attribute on the button. It seems that margins are not part of the "buttonStyle" spec.

Comment: well, i managed with a workaround. Instead of setting margin, I just specified the button below property. i.e specify button2, 3 and 4 are aligned below button1 for example. I did not find any other way out.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this is a bug in Android.

On the other hand, when I started using styles I placed everything inside the style. I noticed that I was creating a style for every widget. Right now, I place position attributes inside a style.

So, `width`, `height`, `padding` and `layout` properties in the XML element and the rest of the attributes inside the style.

Comment: This is a bug in android framework. layout_margin* attributes are ignored in styles if they are referenced throught theme.

Comment: This is infuriating. layout_marginRight and marginLeft are not ignored. However top and bottom are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** If you are specifying layout_margin in a custom style, this style must be explicitly applied to each individual view that you wish to have the specified margin (as seen in the code sample below). Including this style in a theme and applying it to your application or an activity will not work.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    <TableRow>
        <EditText android:hint="@string/last_name" style="@style/edit_text_default" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <EditText android:hint="@string/first_name" style="@style/edit_text_default" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Explanation:** Attributes which begin with `layout_` are [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html), or one of its subclasses (e.g. [MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)). `LayoutParams` are used by views to tell their parent [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) how they want to be laid out. Each and every `ViewGroup` class implements a nested class that extends `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Therefore, `LayoutParams` are specific to the `ViewGroup`'s type. What this means is that while a `TableLayout` and a `LinearLayout` may both have `layout_margin` as one of it's `LayoutParams`, they are considered to be completely different attributes.

So `layout_margin` is not just general attribute that can be applied anywhere. It must be applied within the context of a `ViewGroup` that specifically defines it as a valid argument. A view must be *aware* of the type of its parent `ViewGroup` when `LayoutParams` are applied.

Specifying layout_margin in a style, including that style in a theme, and attempting to apply that theme to an application/activity will result in the layout attributes being dropped, because no ViewGroup parent has been specified yet and so the arguments are invalid. However, applying the style to an `EditText` view that has been defined with a `TableLayout` works, because the parent `ViewGroup` (the `TableLayout`) is known.

**Sources:**

Android documentation on [Layout Parameters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params).

Answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin) by Android framework engineer and StackOverflow user [adamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342605/adamp).

Also, answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453877/setting-layout-parameters-in-android) by StackOverflow user [inazaruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69802/inazaruk).

*I dont want any Credit of this answer* the **real hero** is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13365288/4741746