# Layout problem with button margin

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I have problem with organizing layout in android aplication. I'm dynamically creating buttons and adding them with this code to my layout:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < NO_NUMBERS; i++){

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn = (Button) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
        btn.setId(2000+i);
        Integer randomNumber = sort.getNumbersCopy()[i];
        btn.setText(randomNumber.toString());
        btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        buttonList.addView(btn);
        list.add(btn);
    }
```

I'm adding it to the LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlist"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

and i'm importing this .xml where i'm defining button layout:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:textSize="26dp"
android:textStyle ="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/button"
android:layout_marginLeft="8px"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Well, layout always ends up like this:[image]

Instead of something like this (even spce between buttons, square buttons): 
[image]

To summarize this: I have to:

- describe button in xml
- dynamically generate N buttons
- add properties of described button to dynamically created ones
- organize layout so it can evenly distribute buttons in buttonList with spaces between tham

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Remember, `android:layout_*` attributes are `LayoutParams`. They are arguments to the parent and affect how the parent will perform layout on that view. You're specifying `layout_margin` attributes on your buttons, but they're getting ignored. Here's why:

Since `LayoutParams` are specific to the parent view type, you need to supply an instance of the correct parent type when you inflate layouts using a `LayoutInflater` or else `layout_` attributes on the top-level view in the layout will be dropped. (The inflater would have no idea what type of `LayoutParams` to generate.)

Since `buttonList` is your intended parent for the button views, change your `inflate` line to this:

```
btn = (Button) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.button, buttonList, false);
```

Comment: Umm, I don't think this is the problem at all.

Comment: Well, I tried that. Your solution generated new problem. In that case layoutInflater returns buttonList. Maybe i'm using it wrong. If that is a case, how could I describe button layout in XML and add it to some button?

Comment: ups, sorry, i have missed that "false" in method call :) thanks, solved my problem!

Comment: Glad to hear it! :) `inflate`'s return value differs based on whether or not it attaches the inflated view to the parent specified in the second parameter. The third optional boolean parameter specifies whether or not the inflated view should be added to the parent if it's not null, and it defaults to `true`. (Yes, this is annoying, and we're sorry. :) ) Reference: http://goo.gl/ak6z8

Comment: How to do it for custom concrete view, created in-place, like:
val layout = LinearLayout(context, null, 0, style)  Style margins are ignored here although the view type is concrete.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `layout_weight` on the buttons themselves will cause the buttons to expand without having space between them. `LinearLayout` never adds space between its child views.

You should wrap each one in a `FrameLayout` and use `layout_gravity="center"` on your buttons, then set `layout_weight="1"` on the `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button android:layout_{width,height}="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Well, that "layout_weight" property was my last attempt to solve this problem. It failed, of course. :)

Comment: Did you use the FrameLayout to wrap each Button? Also make sure that the buttons actually have space to expand (perhaps take off the margin parameters on your LinearLayout)

Comment: On my nexus one is different screen size (different from this emulator) and there is enough space but the result is the same. It seems like a good solution but I don't know how could I manage buttons after that. I have to dynamically add them to layout, inflate them with properties described in XML and than do something with them. If I inflate this, what to do next? Please describe how to use this layout after that.

Answer (score 0):

This also worked by embedding the TextView into a LinearLayout (vertical)

text_view.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
              android:text="Large Text"
              android:id="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_margin="10dp"
              android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This was embedded into another view where the root view is also a LinerLayout.
A convoluted workaround...