# How to make Layout_margin in a Style work in java

Tags: java, android, layout, coding-style, margin

I have a style in styles.xml with margin params but it doesn't work when I use it.

```
<style name="detailTitreEntree" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dip</item>
</style>
```

and I want to use this style in my java code so I've done that:

```
TextView tvEntree = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvEntree.setText("hello");
    tvEntree.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.detailTitreEntree);
myLayout.addView(tvEntree);
```

color, style and size work fine but margins don't work. Is it possible to do that with my style ?

sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer given to this question: [Layout problem with button margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin). The solution should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

You should add to your XML the code:

```
style="detailTitreEntree"
```

to the relevant View, instead of adding it through code.  Maybe it will solve your problem.