# android gridviews row height max of item

Tags: android, gridview, row

i have simple gridview. it's elements have different height. for example in row there are one small element and one bigger, next row will align to smaller element and a part of bigger element is under the second row. how can i set the height of each row of gridview to be the height of the biggest element in row??

my gridview

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:id="@+id/new_small_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            />
```

Comment: here is your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545915/gridview-rows-overlapping-how-to-make-row-height-fit-the-tallest-item/7568226#7568226

Comment: give height width of the grid item to be static.if element having different height will acquire the static height provided to it.

Answer (score 4):

For setting cell height, in GridViewAdapter when you write, for example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater cellLayout = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);             
            convertView = cellLayout.inflate(R.layout.gridcell_layout, null);
        }

        TextView cell_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_cell_text);         
        ImageView cell_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.griview_cell_image);
        ....
```

Just substitute this line:

```
convertView = cellLayout.inflate(R.layout.gridcell_layout, null);
```

With this:

```
convertView = cellLayout.inflate(R.layout.gridcell_layout, gridView, false);
```

By this way, setting parent reference in "inflate", Width and Height about cell will set!
Here you can find why:

[Layout problem with button margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin)