# Default custom font

Tags: android, fonts

Is it possible to set a custom font as default in a android application? Because typing this for every TextView is not efficient.

```
 login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLogin);
 login.setTypeface(titleFont);
```

Comment: Have you tried the workaround documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application

Comment: Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647615/set-a-consistent-theme-for-all-the-edittexts-in-android/17648144#17648144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set a custom font as default in a android application?

Not for a custom `Typeface` that you loaded from your own font file, sorry. As others have noted, there are workarounds and libraries to help simplify matters a bit. Personally, I'd look at [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) or perhaps [Fontify](https://github.com/danh32/Fontify).