# Android set edit text style globally in theme doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-theme

I am facing with problem. I am trying to make edit texts in my app look the same with the help of theme.
I have generated styles with the help of online tools (9-patch images) and tried to set it in my theme like this

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="DefaultAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkblue</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/cornflowerblue</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextDefault</item>
    </style>
```

My style for edit text

```
<style name="EditTextDefault" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_blue</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/margin_edit_text_default</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/margin_edit_text_default</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_edit_text_default</item>
    </style>
```

But this doesn't work if use edit text without specifying style manually for each edit text.

This doesn't work

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_text_password"
    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_login"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

This works

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_text_password"
    style="@style/EditTextDefault"
    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_login"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

I know that layout_* params will not affect if they are used in theme, but other attributes should work.

Please help with this problem.

Comment: that's weird... the same setup (although `EditTextDefault` should probably inherit from `@android:style/Widget.EditText` instead of `android:Widget.EditText`) works for me without the need to specify `style` tag for `EditText`

Comment: @blipinsk You are right

Comment: You can also use this line in your default theme `<item name="editTextColor">@color/black</item>`

Answer (score 64):

instead of this..

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextDefault</item>
```

use this..

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextDefault</item>
```

Comment: It's a resource style, which support the api you're running, you can use both.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I use that same logic to others componentes?

Answer (score 5):

### What Should You Do

Use this `@android:style/Widget.EditText` instead `parent="android:Widget.EditText"` .I hope it will helps you .

Please read This SO Answer 
[Set a consistent style to all EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903647/set-a-consistent-style-to-all-edittext-for-e-g)

```
<style name="EditTextDefault" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
```

Answer (score 4):

if your are using appcompat >v22 you can try using

```
<style name="EditText.Colored" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorActivated</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlHighlight</item>
</style>
```

and in your layout.xml set the android:theme propertie to the edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_text_password"
    android:theme="@style/EditText.Colored"
    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_login"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to set EditText theme in a app theme?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fixing the reference to the Widget.EditText:

```
<style name="EditTextDefault" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
```

You need to create a "theme" and apply it in your manifest. Like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/DefaultAppTheme" >
</application>
```

Comment: Can you develop the answer so it reffers to create a generic theme only for EditText? you are overriding the general app theme with the EditText, and it does not make any sense.