# How to set default edittext color in android 4.x

Tags: android, android-edittext, themes

For setting default theme, I set that in application tag in the manifest file.

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And this is the 'AppTheme' in styles.xml.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0400ff</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

This works in Android 5.0 and 6.0 devices. 
But in Android 4.x, oddly it works only for 'textColor' not 'editTextColor'. Although I set this theme, default editText color is white in android 4.x.
I don't know why this problem happened.
Please give me some hints!

Comment: I remember that this happened when I used AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity for using ToolBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer this by myself. I found a similar question. 
[Android set edit text style globally in theme doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377202/android-set-edit-text-style-globally-in-theme-doesnt-work)

It told that I should use like this

```
<item name="editTextColor">#ff0000</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:editTextColor">#ff0000</item>.
```

I used it because Android Studio auto complete function recommended it.

And now I know that I have to use these BOTH!

Android 5.0 and 6.0 follow the color *name="android:editTextColor"*, but Android 4.X follow the color *name="editTextColor"*.

The problem has solved!

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

Java

```
Et.setTextColor()
```

XML

```
textColor="@color/yourColor"
```

Comment: I asked about the situation that when I don't set any text color in EditText like your answer. I want to set DEFAULT text color in EditText.