# Theme with default layouts parameters for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-theme

I would like to set by default `layout_width = wrap_content` and `layout_height = wrap content` to all my `TextView`s. So I tried to modify the theme file with:

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>  

 <style name="TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name = "android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

But if I set a `TextView` without `layout_width` or without `layout_height`, the app stops at execution time.

Can it be done the way I proppose? With big projects it could save a lot of xml "useless" lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set layout attributes (layout_*) from a theme (see [Layout Parameters documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params) and [this answer from an Android framework engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin/5316844#5316844)). You can however set the layout attributes in a style and let each element reference the style like this:

```
<Button style="@style/ButtonBig" android:text="my text" />
```

where ButtonBig is defined like this:

```
<style name="ButtonBig" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>        
</style>
```