# layout_marginBottom attribute on ImageButton ignored when programmatically inflated into a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-inflate

I have an standalone ImageButton defined in xml with the following:

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/btnTourStartGame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tour_btn_start"/>
```

This ImageButton is then dynamically inflated in a fragment with the following code. (Note: ltTourScreenLast is a Relative Layout.)

```
ImageButton startButton = (ImageButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_tour_start, ltTourScreenLast, false);
startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
ltTourScreenLast.addView(startButton);
```

Currently, the android:layout_marginBottom attribute seems to be ignored when this button is inflated and the button sits directly at the bottom of the screen.

My intention is to have the button sit **32dp from the bottom of the screen**. How do I achieve this?

I've referred to the following post but to no avail: [Layout problem with button margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin)
(Sidenote: I attempted testing out layout_marginLeft on my ImageButton and it seems to work. layout_marginBottom doesn't though.)

Comment: is there any view below your Image-button whose visibility is gone?

Comment: @Amrut Thanks for your reply! This ImageButton is a standalone and will be the last element in ltTourScreenLast, and there are no invisible elements around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `ImageView` inside a `LinearLayout`...then inflate that layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnTourStartGame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tour_btn_start"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inflate as follows...

```
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_tour_start, ltTourScreenLast, false);
ImageButton startButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnTourStartGame);
startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
ltTourScreenLast.addView(view);
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! Although the last line of the inflate code should be ltTourScreenLast.addView(view); instead (: Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as the accepted one.

I'm still puzzled why android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" does not work in this case though. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer...Glad to hear that it works...I have no idea...but anyhow it ignores the margin.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give margin bottom in your java code itself using Layout Params

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=showbutton.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0,0,0,32);
showbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks @Priya, I tried this out but startButton.getLayoutParams() returns ViewGroup.LayoutParams and not RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: Try as Hamid Shatu mentioned or else try to create your ImageButton also through code.