# Setting Layout parameters in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

Working with the XML file was easy as I could specify the parameters as

```
<android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

But I am confused while specifying it through code. For each view I specify the parameters using

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I see that I have an option of specifying it as relative layout, frame layout etc.
As of now I am using linear layout for all views such as images, text and also gridview. Should the view parameters be defined based on the layout of the parent element? Or is it OK to specify it as linear layout even if the view is a child of, say, a framelayout? Sorry, but I couldn't find out the difference.

Comment: as far as i know you can do the same with relativelayout tooo

Comment: is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All layout classes (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.)  extend `ViewGroup`.

The `ViewGroup` class has two static inner classes: `LayoutParams` and `MarginLayoutParams`. And `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` actually extends `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

---

Sometimes layout classes need extra layout information to be associated with child view. For this they define their internal static `LayoutParams` class. For example, `LinearLayout` has:

```
public class LinearLayout extends ViewGroup {
   ...
   public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams {  
   ...
   }
}
```

Same thing for `RelativeLayout`:

```
public class RelativeLayout extends ViewGroup {
   ...
   public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams {  
   ...
   }
}
```

But `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` are completely different independent classes. They store different additional information about child views.

For example, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` can associate `weight` value with each view, while `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` can't. Same thing with `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`: it can associate values like `above`, `below`, `alightWithParent` with each view. And `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` simply don't have these capability.

---

So in general, you have to use `LayoutParams` from enclosing layout to make your view correctly positioned and rendered. But note that all `LayoutParams` have same parent class `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. And if you only use functionality that is defined in that class (like in your case `WRAP_CONTENT` and `FILL_PARENT`) you can get working code, even though wrong `LayoutParams` class was used to specify layout params.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on how many views you want to change the layouts on, I think it's better to create a helper method and pass whatever views you want to change to the method along with the height and width values you want them to change to:

```
public void setWidthHeight(View v, int width, int height){
    LayoutParams lp;
    lp = v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = width;
    lp.height = height;
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Remember that setting the width and height here are not going to match the same values in your xml, i.e., android:layout_width="32dp" is not the same as lp.width = 32;

Also, the LayoutParams type variable called lp should be of the type returned by your view...  Check what type is returned by the view and import that type in your import statements.