# How do I set the size of my Bitmap to WRAP_CONTENT and FILL_PARENT?

Tags: android, view, bitmap, measure

right now I am setting the width and height staticly like this:

```
    myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

How can I get it so the width is FILL_PARENT and the height is WRAP_CONTENT

I have been looking online and am confused by all the options available. There's setLayoutParams(), onMeasure(), setMinimumWidth(), etc....

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am making the bitmap inside a custom view that is inside my main activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) to do this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693744/android-runtime-layout-tutorial) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453877/setting-layout-parameters-in-android) might be helpful.

**Edited**, more detail:

```
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    iv.setLayoutParams(params);
    customView.addView(iv);
```