# Crash when setting parameter to layout in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

#### Expected Result

Clicking on the toggle button will show up the menu and slide out the content view rightward. After animation is finished, the layout parameters of the content view gets updated to the final position.

#### Problem

When updating the final position of the content view, the statement `mViewContent.setLayoutParams(params);` causes the crash. The error message is `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`

#### Source Code

**`Main.java > public class MainActivity extends Activity {}`**

```
public void onToggleButtonMenuClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean toggleTurnedOn = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        
    if (toggleTurnedOn) { // If the toggle is turned on
        // Show menu
        LinearLayout mViewMenu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_menu);
        Animation animMenuOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim_menu_on);
        mViewMenu.startAnimation(animMenuOn);
            
        LinearLayout mViewContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_content);
        Animation animContentOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim_content_off);
        mViewContent.startAnimation(animContentOff);
            
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(480, 800);
        params.leftMargin = 384;  // Shift 384 pixels from left screen border
        params.rightMargin = -96; // Exceed 96 pixels from right screen border
        mViewContent.setLayoutParams(params); // This statement causes crash!
    } else {
          // Hide menu...
    } // End of toggle events handling
        
} // End of onToggleButtonMenuClicked()
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- The Menu View -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_menu"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
 
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_row_1_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_search_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:hint="@string/edit_text_search_id"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_search_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="@string/button_search_id" />            
            
        </LinearLayout>
        
        <!-- Other rows in the menu are omitted -->

    </LinearLayout> <!-- End of Menu -->

    <!-- The Content View -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_content"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_button_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onToggleButtonMenuClicked" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_content"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_content" />

        </LinearLayout> <!-- End of Content -->

</FrameLayout> <!-- End of the root linear layout -->
```

Comment: plz put your layout codes

Comment: post your layout xml file

Comment: What is parent view of `mViewContent` params should be added with resp to that, suppose you have parent view as `TableLayout` then, `TableLayout.LayoutParams` must be used...

Comment: Confirm that parent of `mViewContent` IS of type `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @CRUSADER is right, when `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` is used, there is no crash.

Comment: Please don't cut the error message. Especially the `ClassCastException` tells you and us which cast he tries. It is always a great help to see what he can't cast...

Comment: @CRUSADER please move your comment to answer so that I can mark yours as solution, thank you for helping me out :D

Comment: @congliu Added in answer section, with relevant explanation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mViewContent` params should be added with resp to your Parent view, suppose you have parent view as `LinearLayout` then, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` must be used.

***Explanation*** (Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454162/4294399)):-

Take for example, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, they are different independent classes. They store different additional information about child views... say..

- `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` can associate weight value with each
  view, while `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` can't.
- `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` can have values like `alightWithParent`,`above`, `below`
  with each view while `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` can't.

Although the code will not give compile time error because all `LayoutParams` have same parent class i.e. `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. So, it is always essential, to assign `Layout` params with respect to parent layout..

Answer (score 0):

make sure you imported the correct layout params

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Comment: No, still crash when `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;` is added but the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(480, 800);` left intact. @CRUSADER told me to change `LinearLayout` into `FrameLayout`, that is, `FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(480, 800);`, thus, without `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;` it works without any crash.