# Add margin programmatically to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add programmatically a margin top to my `RelativeLayout` in my activity. Using the xml I can do it in this mode: `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`, but when I'm trying to do it programmatically nothing changes... As you can see I'm using some `RelativeLayout` (there is a for loop) in one `LinearLayout` container.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
//LINEAR LAYOUT
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

for (int i=1; i<=3; i++){
    //RELATIVE LAYOUT
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor));

    //CODE FOR ADD MARGINS
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParams.topMargin=80;
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);

    //IMAGE VIEW
    ImageView selectedPhoto = new ImageView(this);
    selectedPhoto.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    selectedPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    //TEXT VIEWS
    TextView numberCopies = new TextView(this);
    numberCopies.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    numberCopies.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    numberCopies.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
    numberCopies.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackColor));
    numberCopies.setText("2 copies ");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsNumberCopies = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) numberCopies.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsNumberCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    numberCopies.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsNumberCopies);

    TextView priceCopies = new TextView(this);
    priceCopies.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    priceCopies.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    numberCopies.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
    priceCopies.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
    priceCopies.setText("$ 25 ");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsPriceCopies = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) priceCopies.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsPriceCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    priceCopies.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsPriceCopies);

    relativeLayout.addView(selectedPhoto);
    relativeLayout.addView(numberCopies);
    relativeLayout.addView(priceCopies);
    linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
}
scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
setContentView(scrollView);
```

I think that the failing block code is this:

```
//CODE FOR ADD MARGINS
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
relativeParams.topMargin=80;
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Got solution.

When you are using `RelativeLayout` inside `LinearLayout`, you need to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

So replace your following code...

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
relativeParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);  // left, top, right, bottom
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

with...

```
// CODE FOR ADD MARGINS
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
relativeLayout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: it works perfectly thanks! You help me a lot! But why in this case you change RelativeLayout with LinearLayout? Wasn't the set margins related to the relativeLayout in my starter code?

Comment: [Plz refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17563292/2345913)... BTW @ChintanRathod **NICE CATCH**

Comment: @CRUSADER, you have already answered the question.. Thanks for appreciation.. ;)

Comment: @ChintanRathod It works like a charm but the margin doesn't appply when I use this on Kitkat 4.4.2 API 19 Samsung S4 I don't understand why

Answer (score 11):

You can use  [setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Try like this..

```
//CODE FOR ADD MARGINS
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

[Layout params should be set with resp to parentLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423707/crash-when-setting-parameter-to-layout-in-android/17563292#17563292) .. in this case its `LinearLayout` as rightly pointed by @ChintanRathod, so

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

will do the trick..

Comment: It doesn't work. I need to add a top margin for each relativeLayout created.

Comment: Nope, the layout not change. Maybe i'm doing something wrong when i add the views or when i declare the first RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that you are using a **relative layout** inside a **linear layout** so you should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

I would replace this :

```
        //RELATIVE LAYOUT
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor));

        //CODE FOR ADD MARGINS
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
        relativeParams.topMargin=80;
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

by this :

```
        //RELATIVE LAYOUT WITH PROPER LAYOUT PARAMS TO ADD MARGINS
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor));
```

Note also that you should use `WRAP_CONTENT` as height configuration for children in a vertical linearLayout. ( in `FILL_PARENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` mode it will fill the parent without leaving space for the other children)

Answer (score 3):

// kotlin

```
val relativeParams = relativeLayoutGeneral.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams                   
relativeParams.setMargins(0, 7, 0, 111)
relativeLayoutGeneral.layoutParams = relativeParams
```