# if I set setLayoutParams() for a layout, what happens?

Tags: android, layoutparams

If relativeLayout is a root layout in a xml, I set a LinearLayoutParams for it, what happens? It will be a linearLayout or it will be subviewGroup of linearLayout?

Comment: It will throw a class cast exception,hence you can't do that...

Comment: It will crash, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17563292/4782930) for more info.