# How to add margins to Widget.MaterialComponents.Button?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

The following style is used by buttons:

```
<style name="AppThemeStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/MaterialButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">#222</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
</style>
```

I know buttons are using this style because their color (`backgroundTint`) is what specified. However, `android:layout_margin` seems to have no effect on margins. According to [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-material-components-for-android-ec6757795351), `Button` is mapped to `MaterialButton`. I thought modifying `materialButtonStyle` would affect every `Button`. Could anyone offer a tip on how to style margins of material buttons?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167529/android-margins-specified-in-custom-style-not-taking-effect

Comment: Thank you.  I believe that is the answer which is still applicable to material design.